# Run-Time Check Failure # 2

Tags: c

i was practicing my C Prog Language
and i decided to create a salon with cashier features

it looks messy,
though i'm still learning

posted here: http://pastebin.com/B2XaaCYV

it say runtime error with variable "menu", but i tried to recheck it around 5x and i don't see any error with it.
the code is really simple
like xy[0][1] = default 0 = meaning not yet purchased. its value will be 0/1 only. it will be 1 when you actually purchase it after picking the hairstyle.

then of course

```
xy[1][i] means price of xy[0][i]
```

i tried using other techniques like removing of breaks and changing variable name, but still it says runtime error with variable menu

no idea what makes the error. so i wish someone can help me with this

Comment: Rather than giving a gigantic code, reduce it to a minimized working version..

Comment: i tried to replicate the error. But i don't know how i will minimize it that's why i didn't put the entire code here. cause its really long though

Comment: The fact of using conio in your example ... I can not compile and therefore I can not help, as uba says reduce it to a minimized working version

Comment: @DavidRF: Doesn't really need `conio.h`. Remove it and you can compile and witness the horror. _Maybe_. It's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%1s",&menu);
```

No! A `char` isn't a string at all. You want to get a single character, so use either `getchar()` or `scanf("%c",&menu);`.

A related error is in your `core_return`, where you try to read 3 characters into a single character. Also, don't call your `main` in a sub-routine. Instead return from the sub-routine and put a loop in your main. By the way, `'yes'` and `'no'` aren't valid. If you want to compare strings, you have to use `strcmp`:

```
// returns 1 if the user wants to go again
int another_menu(void)
{
    char tmp[20];
    printf("Do you want another service?");

    for(;;){
        scanf("%3s",tmp);
        if(strcmp("y",tmp) || strcmp("yes",tmp))
            return 0;
        else if(strcmp("n",tmp) || strcmp("no",tmp))
            return 1;
        printf("Please specify either 'no' or 'yes': ");
    }
}
```

Use compiler warnings in order to find your errors quicker (GCC: `-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: hi i tried using scanf("%c",var) with other scanf("%1s",var)
and this what happen
http://pastebin.com/KsZYqCXP

after picking haircut and picking the style it. it skips the part where i will pick the hairstyle and went directly to core_return func. which not right